# CPU-Wise, How can I optimize UDP packet sending?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I currently have a game, for which I have implemented a client and a server.

I then have the server sending data to the client about it's position, the client sending movement inputs into the server, etc.

The problem is that the CPU skyrockets to 100%. I have directly connected the high usage to the following code, which is in an update() method that is called ten times per second:

```
try{
        sendToClientUDP(("ID:" + String.valueOf(uid)));
        sendToClientUDP(("Scale:" + GameServer.scale));

        for (Clients cl : GameServer.players){
            //sendToClient(("newShip;ID:" + cl.uid).getBytes(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
            sendToClientUDP((("UID:" + cl.uid +";x:" + cl.x)));
            sendToClientUDP((("UID:" + cl.uid +";y:" + cl.y)));
            sendToClientUDP((("UID:" + cl.uid +";z:" + cl.z)));
            sendToClientUDP((("UID:" + cl.uid +";Rotation:" + (cl.rotation))));
            cl.sendToClientUDP(new String("newShip;ID:" + uid));
            sendToClientUDP(new String("newShip;ID:" + cl.uid));
        }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Removing the code, and the high CPU usage disappears.

Here is my `sendToClientUDP()` method.

```
public void sendToClientUDP(String str){
        if (!NPC){ //NPC is checking if it is a computer-controlled player.
        UDP.sendData(str.getBytes(), ip, port);
        }
    }
```

And here is my UDP.sendData() method:

```
public static void sendData(String data, InetAddress ip, int port) {
    sendData(data.getBytes(), ip, port);
}

public static void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress ip, int port) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, port);
    try {
        socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why is so much CPU being used simply by sending UDP packets? And what, if anything, can I do to reduce it?

Comment: Err, send all that stuff in a single datagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take out or optimise the code which is producing so much CPU, A CPU profiler is the best place to start but these are likely to be causes of CPU consumption.

- creating Strings and byte[] are expensive, I would avoid doing those.
- creating multiple packets instead of batching them is also expensive.
- Creating a new DatagramPacket can be avoided.
- I would remove duplication between messages as this adds redundant work you can avoid.
- you might consider using a binary format to avoid the translation overhead of convert to/from text.
- There is almost never a good time to use `new String()` it is almost certainly redundant.

EDIT: This is what I had in mind. Instead of sending 5 packets per client, you send just one packet, total. For ten clients you send 1/50 of the packets, reducing the overhead.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by peter on 31/07/15.
 */
public class PacketSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PacketSender ps = new PacketSender(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 12345);
        List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            clients.add(new Client());

        for(int t = 0; t< 3;t++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            int tests = 100000;
            for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
                ps.sendData(1234, 1, clients);
            }
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.printf("Sent %,d messages per second%n", (long) (tests * 1e9 / time));
        }
    }


    final ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer> bufferTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> ByteBuffer.allocate(8192).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()));
    final ThreadLocal<DatagramSocket> socketTL;
    final ThreadLocal<DatagramPacket> packetTL;

    public PacketSender(InetAddress address, int port) {
        socketTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
            try {
                return new DatagramSocket(port, address);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        });
        packetTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new DatagramPacket(bufferTL.get().array(), 0, address, port));
    }

    public void sendData(int uid, int scale, List<Client> clients) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer b = bufferTL.get();
        b.clear();
        b.putInt(uid);
        b.putInt(scale);
        b.putInt(clients.size());
        for (Client cl : clients) {
            b.putInt(cl.x);
            b.putInt(cl.y);
            b.putInt(cl.z);
            b.putInt(cl.rotation);
            b.putInt(cl.uid);
        }
        DatagramPacket dp = packetTL.get();
        dp.setData(b.array(), 0, b.position());
        socketTL.get().send(dp);
    }

    static class Client {
        int x,y,z,rotation,uid;
    }
}
```

When this performance test runs it prints

```
Sent 410,118 messages per second
Sent 458,126 messages per second
Sent 459,499 messages per second
```

---

Edit: to write/read text you can do the following.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

/**
 * Created by peter on 09/08/2015.
 */
public enum ByteBuffers {
    ;
    /**
     * Writes in ISO-8859-1 encoding. This assumes string up to 127 bytes long.
     *
     * @param bb to write to
     * @param cs to write from
     */
    public static void writeText(ByteBuffer bb, CharSequence cs) {
        // change to stop bit encoding to have lengths > 127
        assert cs.length() < 128;
        bb.put((byte) cs.length());
        for (int i = 0, len = cs.length(); i < len; i++)
            bb.put((byte) cs.charAt(i));
    }

    public static StringBuilder readText(ByteBuffer bb, StringBuilder sb) {
        int len = bb.get();
        assert len >= 0;
        sb.setLength(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            sb.append((char) (bb.get() & 0xFF));
        return sb;
    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> SB = new ThreadLocal<>() {
        @Override
        protected Object initialValue() {
            return new StringBuilder();
        }
    };

    public static String readText(ByteBuffer bb) {
        // TODO use a string pool to reduce String garbage.
        return readText(bb, SB.get()).toString();
    }
}
```

If you need something more complicated you should consider using [Chronicle-Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/tree/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes) which I wrote. It has

- support for 64-bit memory sizes, including memory mapping 64-bit.
- thread safe operation off heap.
- UTF-8 encoding of strings.
- compressed types such as stop bit encoding.
- automatic string pooling to reduce garbage.
- deterministic clean up of off heap resources via reference counting.

Comment: That's what I'm asking you about. I've already tried taking out the code, which solves the issue, but it is vital to the game and cannot be taken out. Creating multiple packets must indeed be expensive, but surely not to the point where 100 packets per second equals 100% CPU? If that really is the case, how does *ANY* public game even use CPU in a real-time environment?

Comment: I just saw your edit. How can I avoid creating a DatagramPacket? Also, how can I not create a String or a byte[]?

Comment: @Joehot200 without profiling you application you can only guess what it is doing, but I suspect your String creation and getBytes() is actually more expensive than sending so many packets.  BTW Why don't you sned just one each time?

Comment: You can write binary to a ByteBuffer which wraps a byte[] and reuse it each time along with the DatagramPacket.  This way you create just one of each of these, ever. No Strings or StringBuilders required

Comment: "Why don't you send just one each time" - You mean one packet, that is some sort of decodable class or something, that has all the data about an object? Would that even be possible?

Comment: You create one ByteBuffer in a ThreadLocal (or use a single threaded component) so You have one of these, ever, This wraps a byte[], so you have one of those, ever, You create one DatagramPacket.  You put into the ByteBuffer all the data you need in one go for the one packet you will send.  You take the byte[] from the ByteBuffer and that is what you send.

Comment: I know everything else, but what's a ThreadLocal? Also, how do I add the bytes to the ByteBuffer without having to constantly change the allocated size?

Comment: ThreadLocal is a field which has a local copy for each thread. This avoids needing to worry about the overhead of locking a shared component. It is in java.lang. I suggest you familiarise your self with all the classes in this package.  You make the buffer larger than you will ever needed and you won't need to resize it. Or you can use one of my libraries which does this for you.

Comment: @Joehot200 I have added a working example. It can do 400K/s in 1 CPU so 100 messages per second should be less than 1% of a CPU.

Comment: I have a single but very important issue with your packet sending - I can't send strings. And no matter how many int's or whatever I send, I absolutely require strings for certain identification and decoding of the packets. How can I get around such that limitation and send strings?

Comment: @Joehot200 You can write a function to write a string as bytes and read it back in.

Comment: Ugh, I thought i was experienced before you came along. Can't find anything on google about it though, they all use solutions that use `getBytes()`. How do I write a string as bytes without using that function?

Comment: @Joehot200 I work on systems which can run a day without a minor collection.  This is a rather extreme use case. I can add a simple method which assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding and can be used GC-free